# Reliable HTTPClient For Symfony 3.4

Tags: httprequest, symfony-3.4

I've spent a few hours looking for a reliable httpClient for my Symfony3.4 (php 7.2) project. I need to get data from an external API endpoint. I tried:

- symfony/http-client (didn't work since it's created for symfony 4.3 and higher)
- guzzle/http-client (didn't work, because I received an error that GuzzleHttp\Client service doesn't exist)
- php-http/httplug-bundle (didn't work as well due to "Unexpected exception when instantiating class.")

Maybe someone could suggest a reliable and working library for making api requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our Symfony 3.4 project, we use the [`kriswallsmith/buzz`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) bundle to perform HTTP requests.